# How to insert a BST as a Node of a BST

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to coding and this is my first post on stack overflow :)

I have a text file of 98K+ english words that I read from and I need to create a BSTDictionary containing inner dictionaries associating a String of letters with each word in the text file, find the letter that appears after that String of letters, and store it in a dictionary as a key whose value is the probability of that letter appearing after the given string. And I can only use a Binary Search Tree data structure no hashtables or anything.

This is for part of a program that generates random pronounceable words and this method's purpose is to statistically insert the best fitting next letter of the randomly generated word.

An example would be <"ing", 
<"a", 0.4> <"b", 0.25> <"c", 0.33>>

meaning that "a" comes after "ing" 40% of the time, "b" comes after ing 25%, "c" 33% ,etc.

Here is my BSTDictioary class:

```
    public class BSTDictionary<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Iterable<K>
{    
    private static class BSTNode<K,V>
  {
    private K key;
    private V value;
    private BSTNode<K,V> left, right;

    private BSTNode(K keyIn, V valueIn, BSTNode<K,V> left,BSTNode<K,V> right)
    {
        this.key = keyIn;
        this.value = valueIn;
        this.right = right;
        this.left = left;
    }
  }

private class InOrderIterator implements Iterator<K>
{
    private LinkedList<BSTNode<K,V>> stack = new LinkedList<BSTNode<K,V>>();
    private BSTNode<K,V> current = root;

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return current != null || !stack.isEmpty();
    }

    public K next()
    {
        if (hasNext()) {    
            while (current != null) {   
                stack.push(current);
                current = current.left;
            }

            BSTNode<K,V> temp = stack.pop();
            current = temp.right;
            return temp.key;
        } else
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}


private BSTNode<K,V> root;

public Iterator<K> iterator()
{
    return new InOrderIterator();
}


// In-order traverses the tree
public void inOrderTraversal()
{
    System.out.print("In-order traversal: ");
    inOrderTraversal(root);
    System.out.print("\n");
}

private void inOrderTraversal(BSTNode<K,V> where)
{
    if (where != null) {
        inOrderTraversal(where.left);
        System.out.print(where.value + " ");
        inOrderTraversal(where.right);
    }
}



public void add(K key, V value)
{
    if(root == null)
        root = new BSTNode<K,V>(key, value, null, null);
    else
        add(key, value, root);
}

private BSTNode<K, V> add(K key, V value, BSTNode<K,V> where)
{
    int compare = key.compareTo(where.key);


    if(compare == 0){
        return where;
    }

    if (compare < 0 && where.left == null)      
        where.left = new BSTNode<K,V>(key, value, null, null);
    else if (compare > 0 && where.right == null)    
        where.right = new BSTNode<K,V>(key, value, null, null);
    else if (compare < 0)
        add(key,value, where.left);                 
    else
        add(key,value, where.right);                    
    return where;
}


public V getValue(K someKey)
{
    return getValue(someKey, root);
}

private V getValue(K someKey, BSTNode<K,V> where)
{
    if (where == null) {    
        return null;
    } else {
        int compare = someKey.compareTo(where.key);

        if (compare == 0)       
            return where.value;
        else if (compare < 0)   
            return getValue(someKey, where.left);
        else                    
            return getValue(someKey, where.right);
    }
}

public boolean contains(K someKey){

    return contains(someKey, root);

}

private boolean contains(K someKey, BSTNode<K,V> where){

    if (where == null) {    
        return false;
    } else {
        int compare = someKey.compareTo(where.key);

        if (compare == 0)       
            return true;
        else if (compare < 0)   
            return contains(someKey, where.left);
        else                    
            return contains(someKey, where.right);
    }

}
```

The method header (I think), might look like this.

```
public BSTDictionary<String,BSTDictionary<Character, Double>> createLetterFrequencies(String n){ return Dictionary of Dictionaries.}
```

heres what I have which does accurately tell me what letter comes next after a String I pass into the method. For example in a main method test I can pass "orang" to the method and the output will give me a printout of letters that come after it for every word containing that set of letters.

EDIT:
My specific question regarding this problem is how to create a "dictionary of dictionaries". If I have a list of characters that come after a string, and their frequency of occurence for each character, how can I use this information to create this dictionary containing multiple dictionaries?

Thanks to all for any help I very much appreciate it.

```
public BSTDictionary<String,BSTDictionary<Character, Double>> createLetterFrequencies(String n){
BSTDictionary<Character, Double> counts = new BSTDictionary<Character, Double>();
        char[] letters = new char[wordArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++){
        if(wordArray[i].contains(n) && (wordArray[i].indexOf(n)+n.length() != wordArray[i].length())){
                letters[i] =  wordArray[i].charAt(wordArray[i].indexOf(n)+n.length());
            }
            else
                letters[i] = '?';
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i ++){
            if(letters[i] != '?')
                System.out.println(letters[i]+ "\n");
        }

return null;}//made null just for testing
```

Comment: This is probably the wrong data structure to use for this problem.  There's a different type of tree that would make this much easier, one branch for each different letter to build upon it's parent.  A BST also doesn't really fit here as I don't see what you're trying to sort

Comment: In order to scale your dictionary to support more than one word, switch your Double (percentage) to an Integer (Frequency) so that you don't need to recalculate the percentage every time.

Comment: @MajoraEXP nobody is going to do your homework for you, much less read your homework instructions. we can answer specific questions you have that can help you understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: @hofan41 Not the intention, more of a response to help you understand how a BST is supposed to be utilized to approach this specific problem. Basically, I want to know how to implement the dictionary of dictionaries part. that is the question. If I have a list of letters that come after a string, and the frequency at which they appear, how can I implement a dictionary of dictionaries using that information.

Comment: Do you have a `put(K key, V val)` method in `BSTDictionary`? And how are there 2 types of values in a BinaryTree?

Comment: You can add that code to your question instead of pastebin, right?

Comment: Will do, thank you for responding. I just didnt want it to get to cluttered. I'm new at posting haha sorry.

Comment: @phflack Referring to a Trie?

Comment: @ryuu9187 Yeah, I keep forgetting the name of it, but it's pretty useful for something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to do something like this?

```
BSTDictionary<String, BSTDictionary<Character, Double>> master = new BSTDictionary<String, BSTDictionary<Character, Double>>();
BSTDictionary<Character, Double> subTree = new BSTDictionary<Character, Double>();
subTree.add('c', 2.0);
master.add("test", subTree);
```

Comment: Thank you that answered the question I asked. Way easier than I first thought!

Comment: I figured it would be :)